# Как в TextEdit получить keyCode клавиши

Tags: android, android-sdk

Ситуация такая: Приложение Android есть EditText на котором не работает OnKeyListener, ну работает но только при наборе цифр. Конечно проблема решается установкой TextWatcher

```
editext.addTextChangedListener(watcher);
```

Только вот беда я работаю с keycode клавиши мне он нужен или хотя бы KeyEvent чтобы выдрать из него keycode нажатой клавиши а TextWatcher такого не предоставляет. Что же мне делать?

Answer (score -1):

как это не работает? Вот пример

```
editText.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        switch(keyCode) {
            //Здесь отлавливайте нужный вам код
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Я же говорил, что это не работает. Срабатывают только цифры, остальное не срабатывает. Работает TextWatcher, но там нету keyCode, KeyEvent event